# laravel throws a mysql error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

for some reason Laravel gives me an SQL error when I try to run the following code. The error i get goes as follows:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from `homes` where `Company` = ?' at line 1 (SQL: select from `homes` where `Company` = Abbeyfield)
```

Here's the code:

```
<?php

class AnalysisController extends BaseController {

public function getSelect(){

    //current USER
    $current_user = Auth::user();

    echo $relevant_homes = Home::where('Company', '=', $current_user->company_name)->get(array());

    /*
    return View::make('analysis.select')->with('current_user', $current_user);
    */
}
}
?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `select from homes where `Company` = Abbeyfield` where is your select column names in your query ?

Comment: @KrishR `Company` is the column name in this query. It is [Eloquent ORM](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent)

Comment: @decker, I didnt find any column name or * infront of `FROM` in select Query~

Comment: @decker Yep that's correct. I'm looking at the 'company_name' of the user currently logged-in, and comparing it to a table containing a set of homes, where I want to retrieve those homes owned by that company (by looking at the 'Company column' )

Comment: @KrishR Actually, I think you are correct. He is passing to `get` the array of column names he wants to get. It is an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the blank array from `get()`. Your code has generated following `sql`:

```
select from `homes` where `Company` = Abbeyfield
```

Mising `*` or any fields because you have passed a blank `array`. It should be:

```
$relevant_homes = Home::where('Company', '=', $current_user->company_name)->get();
```

Or pass some field names in the `array` to select, for example:

```
// Assumed that, id and Company as available fields in the table
$relevant_homes = Home::where('Company', '=', $current_user->company_name)->get(array('id', 'Company'));
```

Comment: Ok this worked, however When I uncomment the view::make(analyis.select) and redirect to it, the $relevant_home->Home_name variable is "not defined"

Comment: If you redirect then you have to `flash` the data to session to use it from next request, you may do it using `with('data', $data)`. That's another issue and I think you should post another question with relevant (non-working) code (if you still need more information).

Comment: Yes sorry just realized that, had withdrawn that bit previously to isolate problem! Thanks so much!

Comment: +1, @MaxF, If you need more information about the redirect problem, you may post  another question with code example.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be something like this:

```
$relevant_homes = Home::where('Company', '=', $current_user->company_name)->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'from `homes` where `Company` = ?'
```

There are no columns being selected. `get` takes an array of column names you want to get.

You are passing an empty array, so are not *getting* anything.

I think you should have this:

```
$relevant_homes = Home::where('Company', '=', $current_user->company_name)->get();
```